# WAMP server in green but only get 404

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp

Alright ladies and gents. I have quite the puzzling issue. I have WAMP server installed on my WIN7 machine at work, everything was working fine and dandy.  Didn't use it for a few weeks because I got pulled into other things. The other day I tried to start it up... The icon was green and I figured we were good. Then I tried to open up localhost and just get a 404 error:

> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

I have no clue why it's doing this, we were working fine 2-3 weeks ago and now nothing. Have any of you had the green icon but couldn't get any pages to come up? Where in the heck do I go because I'm beating my head against the wall here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just try to reinstall wamp server again.

Comment: Did You try to reinstall WAMP? Didn't You accidentaly delete `C:/wamp/www/` folder or all it contents (or at least `C:/wamp/www/index.php`)? Is `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` working at least?

Comment: I will try to re-install WAMP again to see what happens.  I didn't delete anything, all of the files still live in C:/wamp/www/ as they should.  http://localhost/phpmyadmin gives me a 404 as well...

Comment: What do you see in the error log? Wamp tray icon > Apache > Apache Error Log

Comment: Check your Windows Services that Apache is running or not..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is also possible that some other service is running on port 80 (maybe IIS Express, some Torrent clients, Skype..). A solution could be to change the port on which is being listened (as [Mithun Sen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1754171/mithun-sen) has said).

So change the port on which Wamp listens:

- Click on Wamp server -> Apache -> httpd.conf
- Change `Listen 80` to something else, eg: `Listen 81`
- I would also change `ServerName localhost:80` to `ServerName localhost:81`

If you've done this, and saved httpd.conf, you have to restart the Wamp server.
Then use `localhost:81` as your root url.

So the urls will then look like

```
localhost:81/phpmyadmin
localhost:81/mysite_directory
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks for the help I changed Listen 80 to Listen 81 yesterday but forgot to adjust my root URL accordingly.  How can I change my root URL to default to that?

Comment: For some reason, it worked with port 8080 but not 81. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Could be that the port 81 is already used by some other application on your machine. You can replace the port number with wathever port you like, at least if it isn't used anywhere else

Answer (score 2):

For me, all I had to do was click the WAMP icon then click "Put Online", and it went online. It may be the case for someone else out there as well.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the port :

click on the wamp icon -> Apache -> httpd.conf
 change the 'Listen 80' to 'Listen 81'.

Restart Wamp.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the port 80 is being used by any other service. In my case the icon was brown and server was online and `apache` service wasn't started.

Here is what I did to fix it:

In my case `"Web Deployment Agent Service"` was using the port blocking the apache from using it.

Stop the service and change its startup type to "Manual" in properties by default it is "Automatic", this will avoid the problem from reoccurring.

Please find more detailed information on how to find and stop the service in link below : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35252219/5894548

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else has the same problem, I will post how I fixed my issue.

I recently wanted to update my PHP in WAMP to a newer version. When that didn't work, I just decided to download a newer version of WAMP with a newer PHP version. After downloading and installing all the Visual C++ Packages I installed the new WAMP. I also downloaded a fresh version of Joomla, and put the files in the wamp/www/ directory. I opened up WAMP, got the green light, then tried to install the new Joomla. When I entered the URL: http://localhost/joomla/installation/index.php the file wasn't found. I didn't notice that the new WAMP I downloaded had a file name of "wamp64". I took the joomla files out of wamp/www/ and put them into wamp64/www/ and finally the installation file was found.

Maybe this piece of info will save someone else from pulling out their hair.

Answer (score 0):

If you get 
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found. 

even Wampserver light is green check your port 80
probably it is being used by another services.
 So you should do them;

1- Click on Wampserver the go to Apache -> httpd.conf

2- Find Listen 80 and change it to Listen 8080

3- save .txt filen and restart Wampserver

Note: if you have same issue after you restart your computer while port number is Listen 8080 

1-Change port number again like Listen 8081 and restart all services, then click LocalHost. 

2- if page opens again great, but if you had an error then change the port number back to Listen 8080 and restart it, You will see it will works..

---

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the files weren't really there.

I ran into this since I was upgrading from 32-bit to 64-bit.

I had all my files were within `Wamp` while `localhost` was looking for files within `Wamp64`.

So, all I did was move files from `Wamp/www -> Wamp64/www`.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem and I fixed it by changing the Apache port from 80 to 81:

[image]

You do not have to use 81. Just make sure it is not 80 and that you use a port that is free, not something that you are already using.

[image]

I think in my case the problem started when I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2012, I think a service or something took port 80 and then when Apache tried to use it, the port was already taken. Fortunately it is an easy fix by simply using a different port.

Make sure you restart Apache at the end.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

check the port, it might not be 80