# WAMP Server V 2.5 icon is orange,does not respond and no menu

Tags: php, mysql, apache, windows-7, wamp

I have Windows 7 32 bit and wanted to work on wordpress to host my own page but to do that I got virtual server WAMP Server V 2.5 and after installing it, icon in taskbar was orange and after right and left clicking, there was no menu. 
I read many forums, disabled IIS and restarted and nothing. Also uninstalled, deleted directory on c:, installed again but same result, no menu, orange icon. I'm not a tech expert, so pls 'customize' your answers keeping this in mind. I have no idea how to check logs etc So pls let me know.
Much obliged.

Forgot to mention that hovering mouse over icon it says, 1 of 2 services running-server offline. I typed localhost and an IIS image showed up. So, after disabling IIS and restarting, my WAMP icon has disappeared altogether. So I enabled IIS again but the IIS does not check altogether as its 'shaded' (the FTP option is unchecked). After this I restarted and the WAMP icon did'nt show again. This happened yesterday and I reinstalled WAMP as I did now but still nothing. Also inside the WAMP folder, there is no apache folder nor is there any menu display from the WAMP icon on taskbar as mentioned above. Which other way is there to find out about the port my WAMP is using. And I dont have Skype.

Comment: Do you actually use IIS? If not uninstall it, if you do, IIS and Apache are both web servers SO OF COURSE THEY BOTH TRY AND USE tcp port 80.

Comment: ORANGE ICON = One of the services has not been able to start.You need to find which service is not started. Run services.exe and look for `wampapache` and `wampmysqld` which one is started and which one is not?

Comment: I mentioned below that wampserver menu is displaying now. so thanks riggsfolly-have a direction now. checked from apache-test port 80 that iis is using it. went to programsfeatures, could'nt find iss for uninstall option but when i chose 'turn win features off', it was there. could i do that and restart? thanks

Comment: got it green by changing port via administrative tools/iis/default web site (right click)-edit bindings, edit port no to 8080. then restart all services from wamp icon on taskbar. thanks for working out all the steps riggsfolly

Comment: thanks so much riggsfolly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had also that problem, there might be another program running on the same ports, I know skype can be difficult to run with wamp and xammp servers.

Check out if something else is running on same ports and turn skype off = the fix :))

edit: netstat -a -b will show all listening ports and the executable name 
If you prefer a graphical version, Microsoft's TCPView will show you the same information, updating in real-time.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

if you have other programmes running on the same ports you will have to change the ports of your virtual server.

Comment: I am there but whose port do I look for

Comment: 80 or 8080 I think so, will check on the internet in 5 minutes

edit: go to C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf 
line 170 or something, there should be something like servername localhost: 8080  that are the ports your server is using

Comment: You have got your Port?

Comment: been installing runtimes all this while. my ver is 2.5. looked up the file and this is what it says 
# ServerName localhost:80HostnameLookups Off##.

Comment: its port 80, and 80 is being used by iis. how can i right this? could i turn the iss feature off from programfeatures. would that work? pls let me know

Comment: You could change the ports of mamp. so it is not port 80 anymore;)

Comment: got it green by changing port via administrative tools/iis/default web site (right click)-edit bindings, edit port no to 8080. then restart all services from wamp icon on taskbar. Thanks for your timely suggestions haltlolxd

Comment: is it possible to mark 2 answers as both runtime and port were my issues-tried but does'nt work. a little embarrasing to ask this. pls let me know

Comment: I don't think its possible mate:(

Answer (score 13):

I use this way to solve my problem.
Click Wampserver icon -> Apache -> Service Administration -> Install Service -> click on wampserver icon again -> Apache -> Service Administration -> Start/Resume Service.

Done: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75FFNArSPvU

Comment: First of all, this worked great. Second, what service are we starting by doing this?

Comment: @Grez.Kev, it starts the Apache service to serve our local server.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem when running the wampserver.  The icon was orange (server offline). 
Please find the steps I followed to get them working.

- Uninstalled IIS to let apache use port 80 (*DIDN'T FIX THE PROBLEM*)
- I changed the apache port from `80` to `8080` in `httpd.conf` restarting the services and it worked the icon turned green. (*FIXED THE PROBLEM*)

**FIX without changing the port in httpd.conf**

Wanted to find which service/application was using the port 80 
run your command line as administrator and type

`netstat -ab`

*Displays protocol statistics and current TCP/IP network connections.*

Results showed port 80 being used

`TCP 0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING [Can not obtain ownership information]`

googling the msg helped me find the service `"Web Deployment Agent Service"` that was using the port. stopped the service. Updated the httpd.conf to use port 80 again.

Edit : After stopping the service, set its startup type to "Manual" to avoid the problem from reoccurring

Look here for more details : http://benohead.com/windows-port-80-already-use/

Note: I found the "Web Deployment Agent Service" from "*administrative tools >> services*" (It wasn't listed in taskmanager/services).

Restarted the wampserver and It worked, apache now uses port 80.

`TCP 0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING [httpd.exe]`

Answer (score 3):

Did you try switching MySQL ports? If you have another version of mySQL already installed outside of WAMP - you could run into the same problem..

When I tested port 3306 (default sql port) it told me it was being used by 'mysqld.exe' (but not 'wampmysqld64.exe' - WAMP's mysql) which was from a different version of MySQL I had previously installed on the machine and since forgot about.

Answer (score 1):

If the wampmanager menu is not appearing, it sounds like you are missing one or more of the required MSVC Runtime libraries on your system.

There are a number that WampManager/Apache/MySQL/PHP require but as WAMPServer can install Apache versions back as far as Apache 2.22 and PHP version back to PHP5.3.5 it is simpler to make sure you have a complete set.

Please make sure you have the latest version of all of these Microsoft C/C++ Redistributable runtime libraries. You dont need the whole compiler, just these C/C++ runtime libraries.

**FOR WAMPServer 32bit**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

**If you are using WampServer 2.4 or 2.5 32bit and therefore Apache 2.4.x**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 is required](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)  And select vcredist_x86.exe

Later versions may also require

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2014](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40784) and select vcredist_x86.exe

[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840)  and select vcredist_x86.exe

**FOR WAMPServer 64bit**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

```
Yes you need the x86 Package regardless as
wampmanager is a 32bit exe even on a 64 bit install
```

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

**If you are using WampServer 2.4 64bit**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)  And select vcredist_x64.exe

Later versions may also require

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2014](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40784) and select vcredist_x86.exe

[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840) and select vcredist_x64.exe

**BIG NOTE**

The names of these runtime installs are almosts all called vcredist_x86.exe !!! So download and install them **one at a time** or you will get very confused.

Once they are installed your 'Programs and Features' should look something like this :-

32bit systems
[image: 32bit system]

64bit systems
[image: 64bit system]

Comment: I am downloading the 2012 ver of vc++ redist (I have the 2010 ver). Also like to add that there's no apache folder in the wamp folder

Comment: There should be, its in `\wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z` where x/y/z are the version number of apache. If that is not there then something went very wrong with the install. You also need the 2005 or 2008 runtime(32bit even if you run 64bit windows) I cannot remember which for wampmanager.exe. Like it says in the answer ITS BEST TO INSTALL ALL OF THEM and they can do no harm.

Comment: got the apache and the conf file but firstly how do i find out what to look for in dos box ports list as there is no port 80/443 there

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what you are trying to say

Comment: sorry bout that mate. i'll deal with port issues later. ok so i've finished looking for and installing the runtimes. however if you refer to your programs and features snapshot above, i could'nt get the first 2005 runtime file as most places referred me to what turned out as the 2nd 2005 file.

Comment: and the first 2008 file is no more in the download centre and there's another file which after downloading turned out to be the 4th 2008 runtime file. the 2010 and 2012 files are already there. pls let me know if the files that are no longer there would cause an issue.

Comment: Probably not. Here is the 2005 msvc if you want it http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5638 and the (x64) http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=21254

Comment: wamp server menu is now displaying so the runtimes did work. thanks riggsfolly so much. the icon is still orange and so lots still to be done. i still installed the 2 more runtime links you provided but the 2nd one during installation says 'is not supported by your processor'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it on another port? Just changed the port of your wamp server and try again. Google out how to change the port of wamp server etc..

Comment: thanks for your comment altaf. my menu is showing now but the icon's still orange

Comment: iis is using that port (80) which is assigned for wamp. could i turn the iis feature off from programfeatures

Comment: got it green by changing port via administrative tools/iis/default web site (right click)-edit bindings, edit port no to 8080. then restart all services from wamp icon on taskbar. thanks altaf

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there's a service running on the port which is needed by the sql server or apache.

Copy this string and save in a .bat file:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5" %%i IN (`netstat -aon ^| find "3306"`) DO taskkill /F /PID %%i
```

change 'find "3306"' in the port number which needs to be free.
Then run the file as admin. It will kill all the processes running on this port

Answer (score 0):

I had the orange status issue too. Apparently the Apache server that was already running from the previous launch did not terminate properly. Hence I had to kill that through the task manager to get the WAMP server running again.

Answer (score 0):

My Apache service was reporting a fatal error on startup which could be found in the Event Viewer's Windows Logs -> Application. You can find your particular error from the event logs as well, if the checklist of common fixes (like closing Skype) doesn't solve it. My specific error was a syntax error on an alias file I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

**I have finally fixed it!!!**
 If you have installed another mysql server for ***visual studio or netbeans*** it will use **port: 3306**; 
 But for ***Wampsever 3*** all you have to do is to **right click** the wamp **ORANGE** icon then under mysql group click test another port;
 it will show you a dialog with **port: 3307**; 
then press OK. Thats it; then the icon will turn **GREEN**;
 Don't forget to say

```
cout <<"YESSS!" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and it ended up being a port conflict.

I opened up task manager, and a Microsoft SQL process was running.
After ending that process and restarting WAMP everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

1 of 2 services running.....
Check the directory of your Wamp installation.....Make Sure it is C....it resolves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled previous older version of wamp, and installed both services and started and works.