# How to solve Wampserver Aestan Tray Menu error?

Tags: wampserver

I have gone through many tips & tricks on internet to solve Wampserver Aestan Tray Menu error but not finding any solution.

I have unchecked IIS from control panel. Installed the latest version of Microsoft .dot net framework and also installed Visual C++ and also i don't have installed Skype in my system.

Please let me know , how to solve it and make it run Wampserver? Please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont mention anything useful like the version of Windows you are using or the version of WAMPServer, however this post should cover what you need installed on your PC for the `wampmanager.exe` ( The Aestan Tray Menu ) and Apache/MySQL and PHP to operate properly on Windows(32 or 64bit) and WAMPServer(32 or 64bit).

Specifically you dont need to install the Visual Studio C++ instance but **Just the runtime libraries** that are released to match each version of the MSVC Compiler.

The specific thing to note is that wampmanager.exe ( The Aestan Tray Menu ) is actually a 32 bit exe even if you installed the 64bit WAMPServer. So if you are running Windows(64bit) and WAMPServer(64bit) you still need to install the 32bit MSVC runtimes.

I believe it actually uses the MSVC2008(32bit) MSVC runtime, but I am not absolutely sure, so on a 64bit Windows and WAMPServer, install ALL the 32bit runtimes as well as the 64bit ones just to be safe. They can do no harm and its quite likely you may install something else in the furture that needs one or more of these anyway and this way you will be ready to go without anymore of this kind of issue.

[The MSVC C++ runtimes required to run WAMPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938739/wamp-server-v-2-5-icon-is-orange-does-not-respond-and-no-menu/27941227#27941227)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the WampServer is trying to run a PHP version which you has removed. If you can't restore it, try to reinstall the WampServer.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you move the files of the wamp server manually. Check the desktop shortcut via right click -> properties to see what it should be and compare it to your WAMP install folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem but I solved my problem by right clicking on wampserver icon and selecting run compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

Check your wapmanager.ini file make sure wasp is linking to it's respective directory:: as in the directory where you installed wamp.

the default is C:/wamp64

So you can replace all the default instances with your wamp home directory.

Example. : from c:/wamp64 
                   to c:/myserver

Then try running wamp. You still need to check if the https.conf is ok

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem after installing a new HD drive in my PC - this caused changing of letters for all other HDs including the one where WAMP was installed. I went to WAMP shortcut in Start menu to see what letter it should be and then changed the letter for WAMP HD via Acronis Disc Director. Everything started working again.

Answer (score 0):

You Must have php5.6.40 under wamp64/bin/php. If missing please copy from someother place or download it