# Showing Error opening of WAMP server

Tags: php, dll, wampserver

I have installed WampServer 2.2 on Windows 8.1.

When I try to start WampServer, it shows the following error:

> The program can't start because MVSCR110.dll is missing from your computer.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You will have to Install this `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679` this link also given on WAMP download page

Comment: after installation of the file, wamp server icon is showing yellow, and it is not showing online.. local host and phpmyadmin is also not working

Comment: Sorry, this looks like you are missing an MSVC runtime. As there is more than one WAMPServer 2.2 version i.e. (a,c,d,e) and some of these versions had very old versions of Apache which could have been compiled with MS Compilers as old a MS-C 6,  If its a very old version of WAMPServer 2.2 you may need to also load the MSVC 2005 Runtime as well. [Here's a link to a post with the relevant links to download all but the very old MSVC 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938739/wamp-server-v-2-5-icon-is-orange-does-not-respond-and-no-menu/27941227#27941227)

Comment: If you have a new question, *ask* a new question. Don't edit your question to ask something totally different.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET In defence of the questioner, I see that the question has been reworded, but in fact that was exactly what the original question was about, only now it is worded much more clearly.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The new question was an invalid edit as it ***asked a new question***. I could've edited my answer to solve their *new* problem (probably most likely something on port 80 other than Apache), but I didn't and instead someone else rolled back to the original question and I repaired the issues with it. Again, please do not use Stack Overflow if you are simply attempting to provoke other users.

Comment: Nacent, could you please clarify your question. **1)** What exact version of WAMPServer did you install on the W8.1 system _the version numbers for 2.2 are 2.2a/2.2c/2.2d/2.2e_ **2)** Did you install another version i.e. 2.4 or 2.5 and then change the question?

Comment: I'll go with @RiggsFolly on this one, your question's unclear, so please provide the information asked without removing the question.

Comment: My probelm has been resolved,
When i was using wamp server my skype was open,
they use the same port so because of that wamp server showed me error.
But thanx to all of you

Answer (score 1):

`MVSCR110.dll` references to the Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable, of which you do not have.

The Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable is required for Apache to run. The reason why your Wamp installation is not going online is because Apache is unable to start.

A [forum post on the WAMP Server forums](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123608) deals with this problem with an earlier version of Wamp, to quote:

> For Windows 32 : Be sure that you have installed the Visual C++ 2012
>   SP1 Redistributable Package x86 : VC12 SP1 vcredist_x86.exe
>
> For Windows 64 : Be sure that you have installed the Visual C++ 2012
>   SP1 Redistributable Package x64 : VC12 SP1 vcredist_x64.exe
>
> **Apache will not run without this component**
>
> In fact if you are running the 64bit Windows it is a good idea to
>   install all the 32bit libraries as well as the 64bit ones. After all
>   64bit windows runs 64 and 32 bit code. You will probably find you need
>   at least one of the 32bit runtimes for some app/utility you will
>   install at some point.

Some users have also said that installing the Redistributable for their processor type isn't enough, so it may be a good idea to install **both** x64 and x86 versions.

WampServer versions `b` and later require the VC++ 2012 version, which can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679).

Comment: You appear to have missed out the important _and possible very relevant_ requirement that the **MSVC 2008(32bit) runtime** needs to be installed always. Regardless of whether you install WAMPServer 32bit or 64bit and regardless of whether you are running a 64bit or 32 bit Windows OS. This is because the wampmanager.exe is delivered as a 32bit executable in both the 32bit and 64bit WAMPServer.

Comment: Also I am also fairly sure MSVCR110.dll is the Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (VC11) and not as you state the 2010 redistributable. Microsofts naming convention in this area is I have to admit _A Complete Nightmare_

Comment: @RiggsFolly I never said that the VC++ 2008 Runtime is not required, in fact I *never* mentioned anything related to VC++ 2008. I was addressing the question, which you never provided an answer to in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember Windows 8.1 comes (out of the box, so to speak) with only one of Microsofts Visual C++ runtimes installed.

It seems a little odd that you are getting the message you claim if you are in fact using WAMPServer 2.2(a,c,d,or e)

> The program can't start because MVSCR110.dll is missing from your
>   computer.

As as far as I am aware nothing delivered by any of the WAMPServer 2.2 releases i.e. 2.2a, 2.2c, 2.2d, 2.2e were compiled with MSVC 2012. In fact as stated on the download pages on SourceForge

> Attention : All the components of the v2.2 WampServer stack have been compiled with VC9 version of Microsoft compiler. Earlier versions of Wampserver have been made with VC6 version of Microsoft compiler. So, You can't mix components of 2.2 stack with previous version of Wampserver Stack components. If you do it you will get an instable Wampserver.

However, if that is in fact the error you are getting after installing WAMPServer 2.2, then that message is saying that you need to install the MSVC 2012 runtime library.
Which can be [downloaded from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679).

You will also need to make sure that you have the MSVC 2008 runtime library installed as well, as wampmanager.exe is an old program as has not needed to be recompiled for a while now [which can be downloaded from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

This runtime will also be required to run Apache and MySQL executables if you did in fact install WAMPServer 2.2.something

Oh and if you are using a 64bit WAMPServer, you will need to download and install the 32bit AND the 64bit version of the MSVC 2008 runtime library, as wampmanager.exe is a 32bit program even if you have installed the 64bit version of WAMPServer and of course the Apache and MySQL will need the 64bit libraries.

If this does not fix your issue, then have a look at the Windows Event Log

```
Windows Key + R to launch the run dialog then enter eventvwr.exe and press the OK button
 - On the left side of the windows click 'Windows Logs -> Applications'
 - Look for the names 'Apache' or 'MySQL' in the 'Source' column which have a error symbol in the first column.
```

The error messages sent here are normally very descriptive and should at least point you in the right direction to solving your problem.

Comment: This goes *way* into more depth required and is incorrect. Please focus on the question asked and do not stray away from moderators that remove your comments. I have downvoted this answer because it is incorrect, and moreover that you have downvoted my own. Going to ask a mod to lock this question because this is getting out of hand.

Comment: Moreover you *clearly* do not understand certain aspects of how Stack Overflow works. When a question is asked it *cannot* be edited to ask a new question, and you also *should not* downvote an answer because you think you provided a better answer.

Answer (score -3):

when you migrate to windows 8.1, **MVSCR110.dll is outdated**. then, it should be updated and installed into your PC again.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: but I'm trying to the best I can.

Comment: `status is outdated` whose status?

Comment: @JeanGkol See the answer I provided for the *actual* answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398313/showing-error-opening-of-wamp-server/28398382#28398382

Comment: I mean the MVSCR110 status should be updated since it is not compatible with win81

Comment: @JeanGkol How did I copy? I provided *much* more information than your answer, and my answer is easier to understand. I will also point out that `MVSCR110.dll` does ***not*** become outdated when Windows 8.1 is installed (*the OP said they have **Windows 7, not Windows 8.1!***), simply that it isn't installed.

Comment: I just found this http://innovationalmind.com/wordpress/msvcr110-dll-error-while-installing-wamp-in-windows-8-1 :p