# localhost directory url drupal

Tags: drupal-7, localhost, wampserver

I'm working on drupal 7.38.

I have my product placed in www directory of wampserver (C:\wamp\www\xyz)

The homepage is loaded with the url localhost\xyz but unable to navigate to any other page.

All the pages open with url localhost\about instead it should be localhost\xyz\about

I have checked the .htaccess file and done some work on clean url.

But the problem persists for a FEW pages. 
Specifically the home page logo.(it redirects to wampserver)

I have gone through some stuff about rewrite bases but unable to find the issue.

Comment: There only reliable way to run this kind of CMS/Framework is to create a Virtual Host, then install Drupal in this case into the Virtual Host and not `localhost/xyz`. [See this for help setting up Virtual Hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938739/wamp-server-v-2-5-icon-is-orange-does-not-respond-and-no-menu/27941227#27941227) and a description of what your issue probably is.

Comment: yeah ..you are right...virtuahost solved this problem...but why there was the isssue in the first place ..i never faced anything like that befor with wamp server..

Comment: Sorry this was what I intended to point you too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618 see the first explanation for the reason

Answer (score 0):

Is rewrite_module enabled in your apache?
If not enable it, click the w icon at your taskbar, apache->Apache Modules->enable rewrite_module

Comment: yes it is enabled....u know if something is to be done with .htaccess file ..and the rewrite base?

Comment: did you modify the .htaccess ? It never happened to me during my drupal installations before.

Comment: yeah i did ,,but the problem wasnt resolved...so rolled back all the changes...now its back to default state.

Comment: Can you post a copy of your drupal .htaccess. Or no just restart all services clear caches, if it still doesn't work reinstall both

Comment: well, the problem was solved..i just created a new virtualhost with my specific product directory...!!